# Chained Functions in Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For `myLongString`, I'd like to filter it by

(1) keeping the first `y` characters *and* (2) make it all lower-case

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <span>{{myLongString | limitTo:5 | lowercase}}</span>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myLongString = "EEEEEEEEEEEE";
    $scope.limitTo = function(x, y) {
        console.log("x:", x, "y:", y); 
         x.slice(0, y);   
    }
    $scope.lowercase = function () {
        $scope.myLongString = $scope.myLongString.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

The text is all lower-cased, but I don't see the first 5 characters slice. Plus, the `console.log` doesn't show up.

Why's that?

http://jsfiddle.net/r9MTc/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a `filter`, like:

```
angular.module('myApp').
 filter('substring', function(){
     return function(str, length){
         return str.substring(0, length);
     };
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CQZAL/

Answer (score 3):

[limitTo](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3alimitTo) is inbuilt angualrjs filter, just like [lowercase](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3alowercase).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Angular, but made it work:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myLongString = "EEEEEEEEEEEE";
    //No more needed here    
}

myApp.filter('limitTo', [ function() {      
  return function(str, size) {
     return str.slice(0, size);
  };
}]);
```

Note that your `lowercase` transform wasn't working, the one that was working was the built in one.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/r9MTc/11/

Cheers